# What would be some great books that clarify the positional concepts of the Queen's Indian Defence from the Black side?

Tags: opening, books, queens-indian

I've been looking for some books that explain how to play the Queen's Indian Defence. These books don't have to be recent or anything.

Answer (score 1):

In my library I've "The Queen's Indian" by Yrjölä-Tella, Gambit Publications, 2003.

The lines showed might be outdated now but it seems to me that the authors have made an effort of explaing the various strategic motifs behind the various alternatives.